# VueJS if / else: the else loads first, then the if loads

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

The problem:
VueJS is briefly showing the "else" condition before the "if" condition loads. This is causing an unintended experience for the user because they should never see the "else" when the "if" is truthy. They should only see the "if" if the "if" is true.

The detail:
I have a custom online store and many different markets. I get back an item count from my server and if that number is zero then I say there are no items for that country, in other words the country is not open yet for this store. If the number is not zero then don't show the message and actually show the items.

Here is a slimmed down version of my code:

HTML

```
<div v-if="count !== 0">Items are in the store, here they are!</div>
<div v-else>Sorry no items in the store.</div>
```

JS

```
mounted() {
  // Checks the location and gets items from server.
  if (this.location) {
    this.getItemsForHomeView();
  }
}
```

I found this: [Understanding Vue.js Lifecycle Hooks](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/) but it didn't help because when I tried moving the function out of the `mounted()` and into any of the earlier ones, like `beforeCreate()` or `created()` or `beforeMount()` I get the same result.

Comment: Where is your data model?

Comment: The data model is in a store.

Comment: Do you need to bring it in with `props`?

Comment: It's not coming in as props, it's coming in from state.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7zrozamv/1/ Shows the whole script section

Comment: This is probably happening because the `count` in the store is initially `undefined`. Does `v-if="count"` work?

Comment: Is it `count` a computed propert?, do you set 0 as default value for the `count` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to handling an empty item count once the data has resolved, you need to handle the case of there being no data yet to count. You didn't mention using Vue Router, but [this discussion of handling async data](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html) still applies: you can either have the async fetch prevent the component from rendering at all, using a `beforeMount` or `beforeRouteEnter` hook, or wrap all the item list markup in another conditional, which is only rendered after your data has been fetched, and something like `isLoaded` (local state) is set to true.